# Should I scale a percentage variable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a dataframe containing variables of different scales (age, income, days as customer, percentage spent in each kind of product sold (values from 0 to 1), etc). I believe it's necessary to scale these variables for using in a neural network algorithm, for example. 
My question is: The variables that are in percentage, are somehow already scaled, can I apply MinMax in my whole dataset or should I not consider these percentage variables in Min Max scaling and keep them with original values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is not necessary. If the variables that are in percentage is between 0 and 1, you don't need scaled them because they are scaled already.

Answer (score 1):

> In general a neural network inherently is able to scale your input
>   features on its own: Neural networks are a form of representation
>   learning and in the end that is exactly what they are supposed to
>   achieve, as opposed to classical machine learning approaches where you need to find a good representation for the features on your own (by additional methods).

Now it still definitely makes sense to scale your features to improve the training process.

1. This has to do with the sensitive field of your **activation functions** (ReLU, Sigmoid, etc.) which are zero-centered and saturate fast.
2. And obviously you can pre-weight your features during scaling if you already have **domain knowledge** of your problem, you do not need the neural network let that figure it out by itself.

For more on this see this nice [overview](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/).

**Best Practice:**
*The recommended preprocessing is to center the data to have mean of zero, and normalize its scale to [-1, 1] along each feature*